# Navigation controller default animation not working in API success block SWIFT

Tags: ios, animation, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

Default navigation controller animation is not working inside the API success block.

```
API.shared.sendData(url: APIPath.getData, requestType: .post, params: [:], objectType: RootObj.self) { (data) in
            guard let responseData = data else { return }
            print(responseData)
            if responseData.success! {
                if responseData.data != nil {
                    self.data = responseData.data
                    let vc = Utilities.shared.getViewController(identifier: MyViewController.className, storyboardType: .user) as! MyViewController
                    vc.data = self.data
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                } else {
                    self.showAlertOK(APP_NAME, message: responseData.message ?? "Data not found")
                }
            } else {
                self.showAlertOK(APP_NAME, message: responseData.message ?? "Response Failure")
            }
        }
```

If I call pushViewController outside the API block, then the default right to left animation is shown of navigation controller. Please help me how to achieve the default animation inside API block?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are calling that pushViewController from the background thread. You should always do UI manipulations from main thread only. Use:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: @MuneebRehman Any error showing on your console ? If you have written anything in the `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` of `MyViewController`, comment out those and check.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Midhun MP. It is working now. I am using a page control library JXPageControlJump and setting pages there. That was creating issue. Thanks a lot for your help!